# Hibernate merge() is removing child objects but saveOrDelete() is not?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

So I have a hotel room management system. The Room model is having One-to-Many relationship with Guest model - each room can have many guests. The Room entity is like this:

```
public class Room implements Persistable {
    private Long roomId;
    private String roomName;
    private List<Guest> guestList;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "room_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getRoomId() {
        return roomId;
    }
    public void setRoomId(Long id) {this.roomId = id;}

    @Column(name = "room_name")
    public Long getRoomName() {
        return roomName;
    }
    public void setRoomName(String roomName) {this.roomName = roomName;}

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "room")
    public List<Guest> getGuestList() {
        return guestList;
    }
    public void setGuestList(List<Guest> guestList) {this.guestList = guestList;}
}
```

I have an API that consumes Room object (sent externally to it as JSON): updateRoomChanges(Room room) and then calls merge() or saveOrUpdate() on the object received.
Let's say the a room is already stored like this in DB, it is having two guests:

```
{
    "Room": {
        "RoomId" : "1",
        "RoomName" : "Deluxe",
        "GuestList" : [
            {
               "GuestId" : "1",
               "GuestName" : "Alex"
            },
            {
               "GuestId" : "2",
               "GuestName" : "Mike"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I am sending this object (I've removed one guest and changed the RoomName and GuestName) to the API:

```
{
    "Room": {
        "RoomId" : "1",
        "RoomName" : "Basic",
        "GuestList" : [
            {
               "GuestId" : "1",
               "GuestName" : "Alex Updated"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

If I call merge() on this, it is working fine, but if I am calling saveOrUpdate() on this, the roomName and guestName is getting changed, but the guest is not getting revoed. What may be the cause for this and how can it be fixed?